# How can i make a game intentionally crash?

Tags: rpg, rpg-maker, crash

I mean, I'm currently working on a psychological horror on rpg maker, and i want the game to crash at a specific point of the game, Hope someone can help

Comment: As you've seen in the other Question, it may not be a good idea to do this.

Comment: You can always add a pretend window that says error, then exit the game. That will have the same effect, without any risks.

Comment: One idea:   write a line of code to **divide any number by zero**.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 this will not crash RPG Maker. In recent RPG Maker versions, all scripting is done through JavaScript, and division by zero is well defined there. So you won't get exceptions or crashes - you'll just get potentially unwanted / meaningless infinities or NaNs in your calculations.